# Why function output doesn't return an expected array

Tags: javascript

This should be something simple, but I miss why this code outputs 'undefined', while I expect to get an array with numbers: [1, 2]. I tried to debug it in console step by step, but still don't understand why newArr doesn't return from the function. Could someone explain, please.

```html
function filterList(arr) {
    let newArr = []
    for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] !== "number") {
            return
        }
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
            newArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArr
}

console.log(filterList([1,2,'a','b']))
```

Comment: What do you think the `return` in your first `if` does?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and good clarification question. I expect it to skip the for loop element which does not satisfy the condition, thereby going to the next element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `return` that is reached inside a function will end the function call and will return whatever you set there.

In your case, you are pushing 2 values in the array, but as soon as you reach the third one `a` you are just using `return`. This means that you are returning `undefined`. You should return `newArr`

```
function filterList(arr) {
    let newArr = []
    for(let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] !== "number") {
            return newArr
        }
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
            newArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArr
}

console.log(filterList([1,2,'a','b']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I expected that the return inside the for loop would just skip the current element. Why this return is supposed to be the first to be reached inside the whole function? Why return newArr is not the first return? I don't understand how it works under the hood. Maybe you could give some link to an article where to read how it works in a detailed manner.

Comment: Well the second return is reached when all the array is consumed. But you have elements that match the first if before that. If you just want to skip an iteration of the loop you should use continue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "Continue" works fine and does exactly what I initially wanted. About how the return works, I'll try to google by myself. You gave me the idea what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

remove `return` in `for` loop

```js
function filterList(arr) {
    let newArr = []
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
            newArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArr
}
const arr = [1,2,'a','b']
console.log(filterList(arr))

// with Array.filter
let result1 = arr.filter(ele => typeof ele === 'number')
console.log(result1)

// with Array.reduce
let result2 = arr.reduce((res, ele) => typeof ele === 'number' ? [...res, ele] : res, [])
console.log(result2)

function stopFunc(isStop = false) {
  let total = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    total += i
    if(isStop) return 999
  }
  return total // return 45
}
console.log(stopFunc())
console.log(stopFunc(true))
```

you can check `stopFunc` function in my example, `The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.` . in your function :

```
if (typeof arr[i] !== "number") {
   return
}
```

return omitted, undefined is returned instead.

You can check document [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer helps to solve my problem in different ways, but still doesn't answer the question itself (maybe my wording was not very accurate). However, I appreciate your time and effort. Your suggestions about solving the task are very helpful.

Comment: you can check `stopFunc` function in my example, `The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.` . in your function `if (typeof arr[i] !== "number")`  `return`  omitted, `undefined` is returned instead.

Comment: Thank you for this example. It helps me to understand hot this return works much better.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from the function immediately on finding an element that isn't a number, and the return value from the function is `undefined` *not* the array you've been patiently pushing numbers into. Just remove that statement altogether.

```js
function filterList(arr) {

  const newArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') {
      newArr.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return newArr;

}

console.log(filterList([1, 2, 'a', 'b', 3, 4]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you clarify please why the return statement inside the for loop returns undefined immediately on finding an element that isn't a number for the whole function, but not just skips the element of the loop as I expect?

Your suggestion of removing unnecessary condition is good and solves my problem in a shorter way.

Comment: If it's a number it gets put in the array. If it's not a number the function returns without a value (`undefined`). Your array is not being returned at all _because_ it has elements that aren't numbers.